# Call django view from another template

Tags: django

I would like to display view rendered content on another template part, for example, i have a django class base list and detail view, detail view are prepared to render same content on differents html templates as preview.html or extended.html, so on this way could reuse preview detail view on list view.

The essence and idea is same as `{% include 'some.html' %}` but passing content.

Could i approach this situation from ?:

django templatetag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def call_view():
  return app_views.GenericListView.as_view(model=app_models.Company, template='preview.html')
```

ajax call:

```
var content = $.get...
$('#element_id').html(content);
```

Anybody could help me please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try making a Mixin that would pass the same data into the context. Or look into [custom context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) if you want this data in all templates.

Comment: Also look at [`inclusion_tag`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags)